# Read XML values Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I want to read xml on runtime, without save it on a path

After my searching i find that, In console application i need to use Console.Out for displaying result

```
xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, patient);
```

In Windows / Web Application we need to set path like

```
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");
```

but i need to read xml with out save it, i am using Webserive where i need to read it and take a decision that either it is valid or not

I hope i define it clearly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you for your reply, i want to laod my XML without save it on a local Path, because saving creating many XML.

Finally i find the solutions for load the XML from class on a Memory stream, I thinn this solution is very easy and optimize

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer2 = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Patients.GetType());
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
serializer2.Serialize(stream, Patients);
stream.Position = 0;
doc.Load(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) object.
There are several ways to load the XML, you can use the [`XmlDocument.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) and specify your URL in there or use [`XmlDocument.LoadXml()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) to load the XML from a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [XmlDocument.LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) class to read the received xml. There is no need to save it to disk.

```
try
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(receivedXMLStr);
    //valid xml
}
catch (XmlException xe)
{ 
    //invalid xml
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq2Xml..

```
XElement doc;
try
{
doc=XElement.Load(yourStream);
}
catch
{
//invalid XML
}

foreach(XElement node in doc.Descendants())
{
node.Value;//value of this node
nodes.Attributes();//all the attributes of this node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Deserialize` option to read the xml. Follow the below steps to achieve it,

1. Create a target class. It structure should represent the xml output.
2. After creating the class, use the below code to load your xml into the target object

   ```
   TargetType result = null;
   XmlSerializer worker = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TargetType));
   result = worker.Deserialize("&lt;xml>.....&lt;/xml>");
   ```

Now the xml is loaded into the object 'result' and use it.

Comment: I have a class of patients, using this class XML is created, now after i need to load this XML in a string or stream instead of Save it using the path & console.out.
string xml = "XML tags created using Patient class".

result = worker.Deserialize("<xml>.....</xml>");
but i don't understand why i pass XML as string here. I want to load XML in a string

Comment: This link may help you understand the concept http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Nimusoft/Serialization106262007072102AM/Serialization1.aspx

Comment: After review find that XML is saved using the below code

StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");

but i don't want to save it because i have more than 400 -800 Number of XML comes per day if i save it than it creates the another issues...
I need to load it in a string or any thing else than i verify it with my XSD.

Currently i save the XML on a path than verify it with XSD, but i try to make it optimize, without saving validate it and take a decision its write or wrong
Thank You